# How to prevent user to login from more than one ip address in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

We have web application(web forms) and it uses sessions to log users in and out.

Recently we received some requirements to prevent a user from communicating with our website from more than one computer(different ip address) until he signs out.

How could I implement that using asp.net webforms?

Comment: I am not sure there's another way of having a flag in the user account to set him to logged in or logged out. If logged out, don't allow another login. You might want to add a "timeout" though with that, in case user closed the browser and wants to login again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without a database where you can flag a user when he connects.
If the same user try from another computer, just check the flag and reject the login.